# How do I set up a database schema for a shopping cart with promotions/discounts?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'd like to set up some sort of schema that will allow me to implement sales/promotions on products, but can be a bit dynamic.
By that I mean: having sales that are not all of a specific type.

For example:
All items 30% off.
Items in a specific category 10% off.
Using a discount code "DISC20" is 20% off your final price.
Free shipping until a certain date

I've seen a lot of posts about discount codes, or x percent off.  That's all well and good, but what if I want to have both of those as an option.  And the free shipping one throws a wrench into things.  Perhaps the answer is obvious, but I'm stuck.

Any help is more than welcome :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, there is not general solution to this, but following would give you some idea about DB schema.
This is not exact solution but general understanding, but the thing is you have a product table in which there is prodId, categoryID, promoID, prodName, Desc, price etc..another table Category which has list of categories and another table called Promotions where you define your promotions i.e. productId, categoryID, promocode, discount.

Now when user checks out you make use of promotion table and figure out what promotion to apply and what not.

Feel free to look into opensource shopping cart that you can customize according to your need http://www.slideshare.net/boneyp/most-popular-open-source-ecommerce-shopping-carts-top-20